QueryTable object not assigning to object variable
I recently bought Microsoft Excel VBA and Macros by Bill Jelen and Tracy Syrstad to expand my basic understanding of VBA. While working through their sections in chapter 18 I am trying to assign a QueryTable to an object variable, and it's not working.
Here's the sub from section 18.4 I'm having trouble with (as written by me, transcribing their text, I don't see any obvious errors):
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim id As String
Dim ThisArtist As String
Dim ThisAlbum As String
Dim qtArtistAlbums As QueryTable
Dim qtAlbumTracks As QueryTable

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column <= 3 Then
            If Target.Row > 3 Then
                ThisArtist = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
                If Trim(ThisArtist) <> "" Then
                    id = "ArtistAlbums"
                    Set qtArtistAlbums = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(id).QueryTable
                    If Not qtArtistAlbums.Refreshing Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Queries(id).Formula = "let Result = " & "fnGetAlbums(""" &_                  ThisArtist & """) in Result"
                        qtArtistAlbums.Refresh False
                        Application.Goto Range("E4")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf Target.Column >= 4 And Target.Column <= 7 Then
            If Target.Row > 3 Then
                ThisAlbum = Cells(Target.Row, 5)
                If Trim(ThisAlbum) <> "" Then
                    id = "AlbumTracks"
                    Set qtAlbumTracks = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(id).QueryTable
                    If Not qtAlbumTracks.Refreshing Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Queries(id).Formula = "let Result =" & "fnGetTracks(""" &_ ThisAlbum & """) in Result"
                        qtAlbumTracks.Refresh False
                        Application.Goto Range("J5")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
        
End Sub

The code hangs up on this line:
If Not qtArtistAlbums.Refreshing Then
or here (whichever is applicable):
If Not qtAlbumTracks.Refreshing Then
Intellihints is saying qtBlaBla is = nothing. So I figure the lines above aren't setting qtBlaBla to the querytable in question. That's my main hangup (I think).
I also have a very similar line of code in 18.3 that goes like this:
Dim qtSearchArtist As QueryTable

    id = "SearchArtist"
    
    Set qtSearchArtist = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(id).QueryTable

... and it works fine. So I tried using ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") to no avail.
In the workbook module I tried the below and couldn't get qt to be assigned as a querytable, it hung up on debug.print, but qt = nothing in the line above.
Private Sub test()
Dim id As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim qt As QueryTable

Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
id = "ArtistAlbums"
Set lo = sheet.ListObjects(id)
Set qt = lo.QueryTable
Debug.Print (qt.Name)

End Sub

Also changed
Set lo = sheet.ListObjects(id)
to
Set lo = Range(id).ListObject
in that same test sub and couldn't assign qt to a querytable.
Thoughts?

In a worksheet event handler you should use Me to refer to the worksheet, and not ActiveSheet (because events can still be triggered even when the sheet is not active)

Set qtArtistAlbums = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(id).QueryTable should raise a run-time error if that specific ListObject doesn't have an associated QueryTable

I tried using Me and it still didn't assign correctly. And I get an "Object variable or with block variable not set." runtime error at the .Refreshing line.
